# What is the correct syntax to access elements ID iterated in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, input, checkbox

I have a checkbox named `disable` next to an input field named `hour[i]`.

Then there is an `add` button which would add a new row (will consist the exact same elements).

The checkbox when checked in any row, should **disable the input field in that specific row only**.

```
<tr v-for="(item, i) of $v.timesheet.items.$each.$iter">
    <td>
        <input
            type="text" 
            name="hour[]"
            id="hour[]"
        >
    </td>
    <td>
        <input 
            type= "checkbox" 
            name="disable"
            v-on:click="disabled(i)"
        >
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button 
            type="button" 
            name="add" 
            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" 
            @click="itemCount++"
        >Add Row
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      timesheet: {
        items: [ {disabled: false} ],
      }
      disabled: (item) => { },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

How do I complete the `disabled()` function to disable the input for `hour`?

```
disabled(index){
    

}
```

I tried with this, but it didn't work:

`$('#hour['+index+']').attr('disabled', true);`

What am I missing in the syntax?

Comment: You should store if a row is enabled or not in a state. If you have it in the items as a `disabled` property you are iterating through then you can just use `v-on:click="item.disabled = !item.disabled"`. You can refer my code here → https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-haze-68nko.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you need to add `:disabled="item.disabled"` to the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you are doing wrong here. First, since the items are in `items` property of `timesheet` you should use `"(item, i) of timesheet.items"` to iterate through them. You need to add a key here. Indices are usually not good keys but since this application is simple we can use the index as key.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <tr v-for="(item, i) of timesheet.items" :key="i">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Second, in order to add new items, the add item button should push new (enabled) items to the items array.

```
<button
  type="button"
  name="add"
  class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
  @click="timesheet.items.push({ disabled: false })"
>
  Add Item
</button>
```

Next, in order to disable an item on checkbox value change, you can just toggle the `disabled` item property.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name="disable"
  @change="item.disabled = !item.disabled"
/>
```

You can also do this by writing a method. Something like:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      ...
    },
    methods: {
      toggle: (item) => {
        item.disabled = !item.disabled;
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```

You can call this method using `@change="toggle(item)"`. You can find the full code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-haze-68nko).

Answer (score 1):

first you should define a variable
to store the value of index : inputNumber

```
<input
        type="text" 
        name="hour[]"
        id="hour[]"
        :disabled="hour[i] === hour[inputNumber]"
    >

disabled(index){
this.inputNumber = index

}
```